# Шанс выпадения числа в Random.Range

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать чтобы можно было установить шанс выпадения числа в процентах.

Например пишем:

```
int = rnd Random.Range(1, 6);

//Для 1 = 40℅
//Для 2 = 20%
//Для 3 = 10%
//Для 4 = 20%
//Для 5 = 10%
//Итого 100%
```

И для каждого числа делаем процент

А 6 Unity почему-то не учитывает и выдаёт только числа 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Потому что вы генерите число от 1 ДО 6

Comment: Random.Range(1, 7); будет генерить ДО 7, т.е. включая 6

Comment: То есть он не учитывает последнее число?

Comment: Да, если числа целые, то диапазон без максимума

Comment: Ну а никакие проценты естественно вообще сделать невозможно - это случайные числа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для последовательных значений:

```
int[] chances = {40, 60, 70, 90, 100};
int chance = Random.Range(0, 100) + 1;

// Где-то тут должен быть бинарный поиск, но мне лень
for (int index = 0; index < chances.Length; index++)
{
    var ch = chances[index];
    if (chance <= ch)
        return index;
}
```

Для произвольных значений:

```
(int Chance, int Value)[] chances =
{
    (Chance:40, Value:180),
    (Chance:60, Value:170),
    (Chance:70, Value:802),
    (Chance:90, Value:-10),
    (Chance:100, Value:0)
};

int chance = Random.Range(0, 100) + 1;

// И тут тоже
for (int index = 0; index < chances.Length; index++)
{
    var pair = chances[index];
    if (chance <= pair.Chance)
        return pair.Value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Функция Random.Range при передаче float-аргументов использует оба передаваемых числа, а при целочисленных int-аргументах минимальное число будет "включительно", а максимальное "не включительно". Об этом, кстати, можно прочитать в справочной документации или даже во всплывающих подсказках в Visual Studio.

Для того, что бы псевдослучайные числа использовать для предсказуемых результатов, можно пользоваться списком валидных результатов. Рассмотрим Ваш случай.

Вам нужно в список

```
List<int> chances
```

внести 100 значений (1 - 40 раз, 2 - 20 раз, 3 - 10 раз, 4 - 20 раз, 5 - 10 раз). Тогда для "честного" рандома Вам нужно генерировать индекс числа из этого массива

```
int resultIndex = Random.Range(0, chances.Count);
int result = chances[resultIndex];
chances.RemoveAt(resultIndex);
```

Получаем индекс числа из массива, получаем число по индексу и удаляем это число из массива, что бы повторно его не использовать.

Comment: Удалять выпавшие числа не нужно. Вы просто подумайте: через сто удалений у вас же счётчик не сможет ничего выдать, верно?

Comment: @AK для этого нужно проверять на наличие оставшихся валидных значений. И если таковых не осталось, то заполнять список снова. Или так, или другой способ "контроля" случайных чисел, или непредсказуемость рандома... /*развожу руками*/

Comment: Не усложняйте. Вы сами себя запутали, я же говорю: просто ничего удалять не нужно. Выборка без возвращения в такой задаче не нужна.

Comment: А зачем числа удалять? Бессмысленная и даже крайне неправильная операция - пока минус.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, удалять необходимо для избежания повторного использования этого числа (для исключения нарушения шанса выпадания, если рассматривать конкретные 100 рандомных генераций). Если Вас смущают "одинаковые числа", то представьте, что это список из 100 разных запчастей космического корабля. У каждой детали 1% вероятности выпадения. И НЕОБХОДИМО (например, по ТЗ) добиться предсказуемого статистического результата - на 100 случайных генераций каждая деталь должна выпасть только 1 раз.

Для этих целей и происходит удаление из списка валидных значений.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, в нормальных условиях так никто не делает. Но если вдруг встала такая задача - проще массив зеачей сгенерировать и перемешать, чем через рандом индексы искать.

Comment: Джентльмены, ну зачем вы учите детей плохому? Давайте возьмём какой-нибудь LootBox из популярной игры. Из него с различной вероятностью может выпасть 40 различных предметов. Вначале вы создаёте List (естественно, забывая про Capacity), наполняете его, пять раз выделяя память и копируя элементы. После этого начинаете эти элементы удалять (я так и не понял зачем - ведь вероятность вытянуть другие элементы растёт), каждый раз копируя все последующие элементы на 1 индекс влево. И так каждый раз. А потом у нас тетрис требует Intel i9 и 16 ГБ оперативки. >_>